# Send large binary data from ThingsBoard to IoT device

Tags: thingsboard

We are using ThingsBoard as our device manager for our ESP32-based IoT devices. We're already using MQTT to publish telemetry data from the device.

Now, we need to send data from ThingsBoard to our devices: A binary AI model (~1MB size) shall be set in ThingsBoard and sent to the device and I wonder what is the best way to do this:

1. A shared attribute that holds a JSON with the Base64 encoded model?
2. A shared attribute that holds a JSON with the model ID that is used to pull the model on the device?
3. An RPC call with the model passed as an argument?
4. Some better-suited mechanism I am not aware of?

Does anything speak against the first idea or is there a better solution?

EDIT: Seeing that some MQTT brokers have a smaller max. MQTT packet size, I will probably go with option 2 if there is no better alternative. That means, use a shared attribute to set a URL from where the model can be downloaded via HTTP.